# Complicated character transformation Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to find any entry that contains '2x6.4T' and convert this to '12T'

Data

```
type                                                   date       free

FY18-EXX-SEE-AB_total-R899XV-584G-6.4T-R10-WOW-v.A     1/1/2020   2
FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-2x6.4T_18T-T6-v.B                1/1/2020   2
FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-2x6.4T_18T-T6-v.B                1/1/2020   2
Hello-SRR-AB-R555XF-456G-6.4T-R900-WOW-v.A             1/1/2020   2
```

Desired

```
type                                                   date       free

FY18-EXX-SEE-AB_total-R899XV-584G-6.4T-R10-WOW-v.A     1/1/2020   2
FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-12T_18T-T6-v.B                   1/1/2020   2
FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-12T_18T-T6-v.B                   1/1/2020   2
Hello-SRR-AB-R555XF-456G-6.4T-R900-WOW-v.A             1/1/2020   2
```

Doing

```
df['type']=df3.where(df3['type'].str.replace('2x6.4T','12T'), axis=0) #ROW/COL 0,1
```

However, this actually removes the rows that contains WOW, when I wish to keep them.
I am still researching this. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
 df['type']=np.where(df3['type'].str.contains('WOW'), df['type'] ,df['type'].str.replace('2x6.4T','12T'))
```

Explanation: the np.where command syntax:

np.where (criteria, True value, False value)

Comment: Thank you. I do not see any changes. The 2x6.T still remains...

Comment: Changes: df3.where => np.where, removed axis=0. this is the place of the false value

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.type.str.replace('2x6.4T','12T')
```

Output:

```
0    FY18-EXX-SEE-AB_total-R899XV-584G-6.4T-R10-WOW...
1                 FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-12T_18T-T6-v.B
2                 FY18-SRV-AB-T670-812G-12T_18T-T6-v.B
3           Hello-SRR-AB-R555XF-456G-6.4T-R900-WOW-v.A
Name: type, dtype: object
```